# PowerShell script to query AD and report if UPNs in a CSV file are found

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a simple script that references a CSV file containing user account UPNs and then removes these users from an AD group.

```
$CSVFile = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the name of the user CSV file (filename.csv)'
$Path = 'C:\scripts'
$UPNs = Import-Csv $Path\$CSVFile
$UIDs = Foreach ($UPN in $UPNs.userprincipalname) {
    (Get-Aduser -filter {UserPrincipalName -eq $UPN}).SamAccountName
}
Remove-ADGroupMember "My-AD-Group" -Members $UIDs
```

The problem is that if the CSV file contains a UPN that isn't in AD, it will fail and give an error referencing that "Members" cannot be a null value. Once I remove the invalid UPN the script will work fine. I would like to add a kind of error check that goes through the UPNs and if one is not found in AD, it won't abort the entire function. I would like it to give an output with a list of the UPNs that couldn't be matched in AD. Thank  you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send a warning to the PS Host showing those UPNs which were not found  and also skip `null or white space` elements on your CSV you could use:

```
$UIDs = Foreach ($UPN in $UPNs.userprincipalname)
{
    if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($UPN))
    {
        continue
    }

    if(-not($usr = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(UserPrincipalName=$UPN)"))
    {
        Write-Warning "- Not Found: $UPN"
    }
    else
    {
        $usr.DistinguishedName
    }
}
Remove-ADGroupMember "My-AD-Group" -Members $UIDs
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help @MichaelSchubert

Answer (score 3):

You can either switch strategy to process them 1-by-1 - suppress the error from `Get-ADUser` with `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and then use an `if` statement to test if anything was returned:

```
$CSVFile = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the name of the user CSV file (filename.csv)'
$Path = 'C:\scripts'
$UPNs = Import-Csv $Path\$CSVFile
foreach ($UPN in $UPNs.userprincipalname) {
    $UID = (Get-ADUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -eq $UPN} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).SamAccountName
    if($UID){
        Remove-ADGroupMember "My-AD-Group" -Members $UIDs
    }
}
```

Alternative filter out any possible `$null` values from the `$UIDs` array before passing it to `Remove-ADGroupMember`:

```
Remove-ADGroupMember "My-AD-Group" -Members $UIDs.Where({$_})
```